# Is it possible to replace a part of an <a> href values depending on the href value?

Tags: jquery, html, video, colorbox, href

I'm trying to integrate Video JS and Colorbox. The goal is to use jQuery to simply change the value of all  href that have ".mp4" in them and then change the ".mp4" to ".html". This will allow the existing code to work and the integration of two. By changing the ".mp4" to ".html" I can place the Video JS Player in the html pages and load the pages within Colorbox. Currently the video is just loaded into the Colorbox with out the Player.

```
<a href="http://mysite/files/myvideo.mp4" class="cboxElement">Video</a>


$(document).ready(function(){

    $("a.cboxElement[href^='.mp4']")
   .each(function()
   { 
      this.href = this.href.replace(/^".mp4"/, 
         ".html");
   });


    $(".cboxElement").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:640, innerHeight:370});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^` is denoted as `start with` but in your case its not, its ended with `.mp4` so you have to select with `$` ends with attribute selector (*might be said*).

try this: http://jsfiddle.net/QK9Ry/

```
$("a.cboxElement[href$='.mp4']").each(function () {
   this.href = this.href.replace(".mp4",".html");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Without testing it, I think this line is wrong:

```
this.href = this.href.replace(/^".mp4"/, 
     ".html");
```

`^` means starts with in Regex. Try just doing this:

```
this.href = this.href.replace(".mp4", 
     ".html");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap both answers. You will need both of them to make it right.

```
$(function(){

$("a.cboxElement[href$='.mp4']")
 .each(function()
{

  this.href = this.href.replace(".mp4", ".html");

});


$(".cboxElement").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:640, innerHeight:370});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2A3UP/